# Apache Zeppelin is not working with DataStax Enterprise Spark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, apache-zeppelin

I have installed (using source) and configured Apache Zeppelin 0.6.2 with cassandra-spark-1.4 and i am getting the following error when i run the following code against my DSE 4.8.9 cluster:

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("system","schema_keyspaces")
println("Row count:" + rdd.count)

import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
rdd: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD[com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow] = CassandraTableScanRDD[40] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:15
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 7 in stage 10.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 7.3 in stage 10.0 (TID 61, 10.0.202.92): java.io.InvalidClassException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.ReadConf; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -3667529358851109654, local class serialVersionUID = 3501004518838037210
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:616)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1273)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1264)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1457)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Comment: This is a version mismatch error caused by two different versions of the connector

Comment: @RussS Thanks for the response. Yes. But i am not able to figure out what version is mismatched here. My DSE version is 4.8.9 that means its running Spark 1.4.2 and as well the Cassandra-Spark-Connector is 1.4. I have installed Zeppelin with cassandra-spark-1.4. So i am not able to understand what versions are missing here.

Comment: The connector version is mismatched, the spark version should be fine

Comment: Cool. I got it. The connector version in DSE was 1.4.4 and i was building zeppelin with 1.4.2. Thanks RussS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this blog post. He has made an extensive explanation of building zeppelin with Cassandra and DSE
http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=2325

Comment: Thanks Vincent. I got it to work.The connector version in DSE was 1.4.4 and i was building zeppelin with 1.4.2.